# How to declare type of variable retrieved by TryGetValue if the dictionary is of generic type?

Tags: c#, generics

I have a following field declared in my class -

```
private Dictionary<T, List<IEventProcessor<T>>> _subscribers = new Dictionary<T, List<IEventProcessor<T>>> ();
```

I also have the following method:

```
public GenEvent<T> GetEvent ()
```

one of the methods of this class needs to lookup an event processor from the _subscribers dictionary. How do I declare the type of local variable list?

```
public void Process()
{
   var ev = GetEvent();
   TYPE list;
   if (_subscribers.TryGetValue(ev.EType,  out list) ){
            foreach (var sub in list) {
                // do something 
            }
    }
```

Comment: I'm curious - what's the type of `ev.EType`? If it's `T` then the answer to this question is trivial. If it's `System.Type` then it's a different, more complex issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should look like this:

```
public class MyClass<T>
{
    private Dictionary<T, List<IEventProcessor<T>>> _subscribers = new Dictionary<T, List<IEventProcessor<T>>> ();

    public GenEvent<T> GetEvent() {}

    public void Process()
    {
        GenEvent<T> ev = GetEvent();
        List<IEventProcessor<T>> list;
        if (_subscribers.TryGetValue(ev.EType, out list) )
        {
            foreach (IEventProcessor<T> sub in list) 
            {
                // do something 
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I was hoping to avoid decorating Process with <T>.

Comment: @AlbertoPier My bad, you don't have to decorate `Process` since your class is already decorated.

Answer (score 2):

```
List<IEventProcessor<T>> list;
```